# Is enumerate in python lazy?

Tags: python, iterator, generator, enumerate

I'd like to know what happens when I pass the result of a generator function to python's enumerate(). Example:

```
def veryBigHello():
    i = 0
    while i < 10000000:
        i += 1
        yield "hello"

numbered = enumerate(veryBigHello())
for i, word in numbered:
    print i, word
```

Is the enumeration iterated lazily, or does it slurp everything into the `<enumerate object>` first? I'm 99.999% sure it's lazy, so can I treat it exactly the same as the generator function, or do I need to watch out for anything?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

It's lazy.  It's fairly easy to prove that's the case:

```
>>> def abc():
...     letters = ['a','b','c']
...     for letter in letters:
...         print letter
...         yield letter
...
>>> numbered = enumerate(abc())
>>> for i, word in numbered:
...     print i, word
...
a
0 a
b
1 b
c
2 c
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3 (or both)? Is it lazy in both? I tested on Python 2 and it *is* lazy.

Comment: I tested this on Python 3.5.2, and it evaluates lazily.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks.  So basically there's no cost overhead to wrapping a generator in `enumerate` is the takeaway, right?  It won't parse the object N times...

Answer (score 56):

It's even easier to tell than either of the previous suggest:

```
$ python
Python 2.5.5 (r255:77872, Mar 15 2010, 00:43:13)
[GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> abc = (letter for letter in 'abc')
>>> abc
<generator object at 0x7ff29d8c>
>>> numbered = enumerate(abc)
>>> numbered
<enumerate object at 0x7ff29e2c>
```

If enumerate didn't perform lazy evaluation it would return `[(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]` or some (nearly) equivalent.

Of course, enumerate is really just a fancy generator:

```
def myenumerate(iterable):
   count = 0
   for _ in iterable:
      yield (count, _)
      count += 1

for i, val in myenumerate((letter for letter in 'abc')):
    print i, val
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I had a bit of a hard time figuring out the accepted answer. At least until I saw yours.

Comment: It could perform eager evaluation and still display as `<enumerate object at 0x7ff29e2c>`.

Answer (score 15):

Since you can call this function without getting out of memory exceptions it definitly is lazy

```
def veryBigHello():
    i = 0
    while i < 1000000000000000000000000000:
        yield "hello"

numbered = enumerate(veryBigHello())
for i, word in numbered:
    print i, word
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school alternative since I was using a generator that someone else (sklearn) wrote that didn't work with the approaches here.

```
i=(-1)
for x in some_generator:
    i+=1
```